# How to refresh a pop-up window using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using

```
window.open("http://something...")
```

to open a pop-up window which shows a PDF file with some report on it when certain ajax success gets hit. However my PDF file doesn't show the updated data every-time I open the pop-up window. If I manually hit the F5 or refresh the page it shows the updated data. 
I tried something like this but to no avail.

```
window.open("http://something...").location.reload();
```

How can I refresh the pop-up window everytime it loads.

Comment: pdf=window.open(); pdf.location="newurl";

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can append a timestamp into the url to avoid the browser cache

```
var url = "http:/myurl/myFile.pdf?"+ Date.now();
window.open(url);
```

for older browsers that doesn't support [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) you can use *`new Date().getTime();`*

Comment: What about `"http:/myurl/myFile.pdf?"+ Date.now()`

Comment: Ok i feel extremely stupid but I did try both  + new Date().getTime(); and Math.random() etc. and it wasnt working before. Seems like I was misplacing "?" somewhere. This does solve my problem but I would love to know how to refresh the pop-up window too

Comment: @BibekAryal here is a way how to refresh de window https://plnkr.co/edit/9BEyCqCnUWzq8B5jE8ac?p=preview